# SQL Server - TimeStamp Gaps

Tags: sql-server, time, nested, timestamp

i just started learning SQL and i'm reading a book called "The Guru's Guide To Transact SQL" by Ken Henderson. In the Book it gives me this table:

```
CREATE TABLE timeclock
(
     Employee varchar(30),
     TimeIn smalldatetime,
     TimeOut smalldatetime
)

INSERT timeclock VALUES('Pythia','07:31:34','12:04:01')
INSERT timeclock VALUES('Pythia','12:45:10','17:32:49')
INSERT timeclock VALUES('Dionysus','9:31:29','10:46:55')
INSERT timeclock VALUES('Dionysus','10:59:32','11:39:12')
INSERT timeclock VALUES('Dionysus','13:05:16','14:07:41')
INSERT timeclock VALUES('Dionysus','14:11:49','14:57:02')
INSERT timeclock VALUES('Dionysus','15:04:12','15:08:38')
INSERT timeclock VALUES('Dionysus','15:10:31','16:13:58')
INSERT timeclock VALUES('Dionysus','16:18:24','16:58:01')
```

Then it gives a block of code where it queries the amount of time an employee is out of the office:

```
SELECT 
    t1.Employee, t1.TimeOut AS StartOfLoafing,
    t2.TimeIn AS EndOfLoafing,
    DATEDIFF(mi,t1.TimeOut,t2.TimeIn) AS LengthOfLoafing
FROM 
    timeclock t1 
JOIN 
    timeclock t2 ON (t1.Employee = t2.Employee)
WHERE 
    (t1.TimeOut = (SELECT MAX(t3.TimeOut)
                   FROM timeclock t3
                   WHERE (t3.Employee=t1.Employee) AND (t3.TimeOut <= t2.TimeIn)))
```

I tried reading the explanation for this query, however I still don't understand lines 5-7 (the nested part really throws me off). It seems like it's iterating the table? Could someone please explain it in detail for a beginner please.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It appears to be filtering out records who are currently in the office.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend a book from 2000 to start learning SQL. I'd recommend starting with https://www.khanacademy.org/computing/computer-programming/sql or http://www.w3schools.com/sql/ and later Louis Davidson's book on design and implementation http://www.drsql.org/Pages/ProSQLServerDatabaseDesign.aspx to start.

Answer (score 0):

The query above generating a Cartesian product of employees and their timein/timeout with the join. It is using the `where t1.timeout=` sub query to get the most recent (using `max` in this case) `timeout` that is less than `t2.TimeIn`.

That query could also be written like this:

```
select
      t1.Employee
    , StartOfLoafing  = t1.TimeOut
    , EndOfLoafing    = t2.TimeIn 
    , LengthOfLoafing = datediff(mi,t1.TimeOut,t2.TimeIn)
  from timeclock as t1
    cross apply (
      select top 1 i.timein
        from timeclock i
        where i.employee=t1.employee
          and i.timein >=t1.timeout
        order by i.timein asc) as t2
```

rextester: http://rextester.com/SES2195